# Why ajax request doubles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have an issue, with ajax request. When button enter is clecked it is doubles ajax request. I spent 4 hours dealing with it and no effect at all. Can someone help me with it. I have created consol.log here. For better understanding of my **bad code**. Thank you in advanced!

```js
let formSubmitHandler = (data) => {
  console.log(data)
  // $.ajax({ url: 'index.php',
}
let handleInputEdit = (data) => {
  let onFocusHandler = (element) => {
    element.keypress(function( event ) {
      if ( event.which == 13) {
        let inputData = element.val();
        let name = element.attr('name');
        return onHandlerFormData(name, inputData);
      }
    })
  }
  let onHandlerFormData = (name, data) => {
    let str = `${name}=${data}`;
    $('#data').html(str)
    return formSubmitHandler(str);
  }
  let onEditHandler = () => {
    let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      const element = checkboxes[i];
      let getNaighborInput = $(element).parent().next();
      getNaighborInput.attr("disabled", true);
      if (element.checked) {
        let getNaighborInput = $(element).parent().next();
        getNaighborInput.attr("disabled", false)
          .focus(function(){
            onFocusHandler($(this));
          })
      }
    }
  };
  onEditHandler();
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", onEditHandler);
}
handleInputEdit();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="mainForm">
  <label for="companyName">Label 2</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </span>
    <input 
        id="companyName"
        type="text" 
        class="form-control"
        aria-label="..." 
        name="companyName"
        >
  </div>
  <label for="edrpou">Label 2</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </span>
    <input 
      id="edrpou"
      type="text" 
      class="form-control"
      aria-label="..." 
      name="edrpou"
      >
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you are adding `onFocusHandler` multiple times

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you a lot it was so stupid bug. Thanks one more time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `onFocusHandler` multiple times. You binding the `onFocusHandler` multiple times each time the checkbox is clicked. Moving the `onFocusHandler` from the definition of `onEditHandler` will solve this issue. Try out the following code,
The `onEditHandler` will change as follows,

```
let onEditHandler = () => {
    let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        const element = checkboxes[i];
        let getNaighborInput = $(element).parent().next();
        getNaighborInput.attr("disabled", true);
        if (element.checked) {
            let getNaighborInput = $(element).parent().next();
            getNaighborInput.attr("disabled", false)

        }
    }
};
```

And bind the `onFocusHandler` function with the checkboxes only once as follows,

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    onFocusHandler($(this).parent().next());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have re-written the javascript to handle enabling/disabling the textboxes, and also to handle `keyup` event for the ENTER press.

I think the code is more readable this way, plus: it works as expected.

```js
// disable all textboxes by default
$('input[type=text]').attr('disabled','disabled');

//only enable the textbox next to the checkbox if it was checked
$(document).on('click','input[type=checkbox]',function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

        $(this).parent().siblings('input[type=text]')
                        .removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {

        $(this).parent().siblings('input[type=text]')
                        .attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
});


//whenever the ENTER key is pressed within an enabled textbox, handle it
$(document).on('keyup','input[type=text]',function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        console.log( $(this).attr('id') + '=' + $(this).val() );
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="mainForm">
  <label for="companyName">Label 2</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </span>
    <input 
        id="companyName"
        type="text" 
        class="form-control"
        aria-label="..." 
        name="companyName"
        >
  </div>
  <label for="edrpou">Label 2</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </span>
    <input 
      id="edrpou"
      type="text" 
      class="form-control"
      aria-label="..." 
      name="edrpou"
      >
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It just amazing. Thank you Ahmed!

Answer (score 0):

Like [Ahmad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736172/ahmad)... I also re-written your **way too complex** code.

It made my brain bleed.
And it does a so simple task in the end!

About changes on HTML, I only added the `disabled` attribute straith in the markup.

**Have a look:**

```js
$("#mainForm input[type='checkbox']").on("click",function(){
  var text_input = $(this).parent().next("input");
  var text_input_dasbled = text_input.prop("disabled");
  text_input.attr("disabled", !text_input_dasbled); // Toggle disabled
});

$("#mainForm input[type='text']").on("keyup",function(e){
  if(e.which==13){
    var data = {[$(this).attr("name")]:$(this).val()};
    console.log(data)
    // $.ajax({ ... });
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>


<form id="mainForm">
  <label for="companyName">Label 2</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </span>
    <input 
           id="companyName"
           type="text" 
           class="form-control"
           aria-label="..." 
           name="companyName"
           disabled>
  </div>
  
  <label for="edrpou">Label 2</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </span>
    <input 
           id="edrpou"
           type="text" 
           class="form-control"
           aria-label="..." 
           name="edrpou"
           disabled>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank a lot for help, it really teach me be better. Thank you